# Tell whether $\dfrac{10^{91}-1}{9}$ is prime or not?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I really have no idea how to start. The only theorem considering prime numbers I know of is Fermat's little theorem and maybe its related with binomial theorem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300805/when-is-the-number-11111-1-a-prime-number

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just think through the actual number.

$10^{91}$ is a $1$ with $91$ $0$'s after it.

$10^{91}-1$ is therefore $91$ $9$'s in a row.

$\frac{10^{91}-1}{9}$ is therefore $91$ $1$'s in a row.

Due to the form of this number, $x$ $1$'s in a row will divide it, where $x$ is a divisor of $91$.

For example $1111111$ is a divisor, so is $1111111111111$.

Hence the number is not prime.

Comment: Cute.  Very pretty indeed. +1!

Comment: Really, you're not thinking of it in terms of "the actual number" here; you're thinking of it in terms of the decimal representation. The decimal representation isn't any more "the actual number" than the expression $\frac{10^{91}-1}{9}$, and this argument wouldn't work in hexadecimal. Still, upvoted.

Comment: Perhaps knowing too much theorems reduces your strike rate of easier problems. :D

Comment: Yep, poor wording but that's what I meant by thinking of the actual number. A lot of the time the initial reaction (mine too) is big, scary, clearly I'm just supposed to just throw a theorem at it. Sometimes things aren't as bad as they seem though :)

Comment: Great solution but i guess it should be 90 9's instead of 91 , elegant solution though

Comment: no, 91 9's. Try taking some simpler examples, e.g. $10^3-1=1000-1=999$

Comment: No 91 1s is not prime it has many divisors But it is not divisible by 7 1s or 13 1s,

Answer (score 11):

**Hint:** Note that $91=7\cdot 13$, so the numerator is divisible by $10^7-1$.

If this is not obvious, it may be clearer if we let $x=10^7$. Then $10^{91}=x^{13}$, and it is a familiar fact that $x-1$ divides $x^n-1$ for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: Critical hit. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. There is a little more to write to finish the argument, but it should not be difficult.

Comment: So the number is divisible by $1111111$. ($7$ times) Right?

Comment: That;s right, $\frac{10^7-1}{9}$ is an integer, it is a divisor of our number, and it is obviously not equal to $1$ or $\frac{10^{91}-1}{9}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Why $a^n - b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b),

$$a^{91}-1=(a^{13})^7-1^7$$ is divisible by $a^{13}-1$ and by similarly by $a^7-1$

Again, using [Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1),

$$(a^7-1,a^{13}-1)=a^{(7,13)}-1=a-1$$

Hence, $\displaystyle\frac{a^{13}-1}{a-1}, \frac{a^7-1}{a-1}$ are co-prime primes and divisors of $\displaystyle\frac{a^{91}-1}{a-1}$

Answer (score -1):

You have

$$111111....1=1+10+10^2.....+10^{90}=(10^{84}+10^{77}+10^70.....+10^7+1) (10^6+10^5+10^4+ \dots + 10^0);$$
this is product of two integers 2 or greater,  so it is not prime.

Comment: If you could explain how you found those two factors, that would be great.