# Fraction of a numbers digit permutations that are prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Calculate the following number

$$\sup \{x\in[0, 1] \space | \space  \#A_x = \infty  \}$$

Where $A_x = \{n\in \mathbb{N} \space | \space \text{the fraction of $n$'s digit permutations that are prime } \geq x\}$.

The digit permutations of a number are all the permutations of its digits, for example for $n=2399$ the permutations are

$$\{
2399, 2939, 2993, 3299, 3929, 3992, 9239, 9293, 9329, 9392, 9923, 9932
\}.$$

Seven out of these twelve numbers are prime: $\{2399, 2939, 3299, 3929, 9239, 9293, 9923\}$ so $n\in A_{\frac{7}{12}}$.

Comment: I expect it is zero because the proportion for most $n$-digit numbers is below $10/n$ by the Prime Number Theorem, but I don't know how to rule out outliers. Zero is in the set because every number with all-even digits is in $A_0$.

Comment: Is there anything known about the prime numbers among $11\ldots1$? If there are infinitely many, then the supremum is $1$. Looking here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300805/when-is-the-number-11111-1-a-prime-number it seems this is suspected but not known.